# How to create a UI like CleanMyMac X?

Tags: css, macos, user-interface, progressive-web-apps, user-experience

The UI of the mac app [CleanMyMax X](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) looks quite good. Is this created using something that is Mac OS specific? How can I create something similar using HTML, CSS?

Attaching a screenshot of the app:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can but are you excepting us creating it for you ?

Comment: No. not at all. Sorry, if it wasn't clear from the question. I was asking about the tools, programming languages, frameworks etc used for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can create something like this.

make 2 divs(1 for main 1 for sidenav)

get the background color right with the color picker(you can screenshot the background and use https://imagecolorpicker.com/)

in the sidenav add the list with content(smartscreen etc.)

round corners with `border-radius`

you can add images as elements in a div wrappers and centre them as you wish

. . . . . .

When you want to you can use CSS HTML and Javascript for the front end etc.

you can use Angular or React if you wish as well

Comment: Thanks Dev. The button at the bottom has some kind of halo, 3D effect around it. What about that?

Comment: Creating animations in javascript is not that hard. you can use some APIs for it. For example: https://animejs.com/documentation/ When you got all the answers answered close the question ;)

Comment: No, I was asking about the CSS part.

Comment: Oh sorry. Then check out the @keyframes Rule: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: @Dev The question is thoroughly off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]